# Benchmarking/Performance of Postgresql Query

Tags: postgresql

I want to measure the performance of `postgresql` code I wrote. In the code tables get created, selfwritten functions get called etc. 
Looking around, I found `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` is the way to go.
However, as far as I understand it, the code only gets executed once. For a more realistic analysis I want to execute the code many many times and have the results of each iteration written somewhere, ideally in a table (for statistics later).

Is there a way to do this with a native postgresql function? If there is no native `postgresql` function, would I accomplish this with a simple loop? Further, how would I write out the information of every `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to write a function that runs an explain and then spool the output of that into a file (or insert that into a table).

E.g.:

```
create or replace function show_plan(to_explain text)
  returns table (line_nr integer, line text)
as
$$
declare
  l_plan_line record;
  l_line integer;
begin
   l_line := 1;
   for l_plan_line in execute 'explain (analyze, verbose)'||to_explain loop
      return query select l_line, l_plan_line."QUERY PLAN";
      l_line := l_line + 1;
   end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then you can use `generate_series()` to run a statement multiple times:

```
select g.i as run_nr, e.*
from show_plan('select * from foo') e
  cross join generate_series(1,10) as g(i)
order by g.i, e.line_nr;
```

This will run the function 10 times with the passed SQL statement. The result can either be spooled to a file (how you do that depends on the SQL client you are using) or inserted into a table.

---

For an automatic analysis it's probably easer to use a more "parseable" explain format, e.g. XML or JSON. This is also easier to handle in the output as the plan is a single XML (or JSON) value instead of multiple text lines:

```
create or replace function show_plan_xml(to_explain text)
  returns xml
as
$$
begin
   return execut 'explain (analyze, verbose, format xml)'||to_explain;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then use:

```
select g.i as run_nr, show_plan_xml('select * from foo')
from join generate_series(1,10) as g(i)
order by g.i;
```

Comment: The last function you wrote `returns XML`. Where is the file written to? Can I pass it a `path`?

Comment: @Stophface: as I said: _how_ you export the result of that into a file depends on the SQL client you are using. But you can also store the result of the function call into a table.